# How do I keep rows highlighted in a datagridview using RowFilter?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datarowview

I am using RowFilter to highlight rows in a datagridview, but when i clear the filter to view all records it removes the highlight i applied:

```
Sorter.DtSample.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FirstName = 'John'" 
For Each R0w In Sorter.DataGridView1.Rows
  R0w.defaultcellstyle.forecolor = Color.Red
  Sorter.DataGridView1(0, R0w.index).Value = True
Next
Sorter.DtSample.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""
```

Comment: 100K is really too many recors. Don't show all 100K+ records in `DataGridView`. Use a paging/filtering mechanism and just show some of rows.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That doesn't really fit what I am trying to accomplish. I need to be able to scroll through all the records to compare the selected ones with the non selected ones( or non-highlighted)

Comment: So use [`VirtualMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx) in `DataGridView`.

Comment: You'll never get a clear answer as long as you keep using Selected, Highhlighted, Search and filter interchangeably.  Those have different meanings; you can always process the data more quickly than you can root around in controls

Comment: @RezaAghaei is there a way to keep the records i want highlighted after removing the RowFilter?

Comment: It depends to the implementation. Start by reading the MSDN link which I shared. If number of rows are really large, I prefer use virtual mode, then you can check the criteria in `CellFormatting` event to decide if you want to colorize the row or not.

Comment: @Plutonix I have updated the question so that it is not a duplicate

Comment: @RezaAghaei see updated code above please, this is how I am trying to do it.

Comment: There is never a reason to loop thru all rows in a bound DGV.  Use the events (like row_prepaint or maybe cell formatting) to change colors.  When you remove the filter, the DGV contents change, so your coloring needs to be redone *unless* you save a flag *in the data* for those rows

Comment: @Plutonix I am using a button to trigger the search criteria in  text box, how would i use cell formatting to do that?

Comment: I saw the edit. You don't need to use a loop on all rows at all, `CellFormatting` event is what you are looking for. But keep in mind always a `DataGridView` with too many rows will be slow.  Try cell formatting let us know what problem do you have.

Comment: There you go: now it is a *search*.  If I executed a *search* I would expect the program to take me to the row where `Name='Ziggy'`, then maybe a function to take me to the next one.  I would **not** expect it to change the forecolor of 1 cell in a sea of  (100000 * #columns) and leave me to find it.

Comment: @Plutonix yes, but i would like to view the "colored" records against the non-colored records

Comment: I have to semi-disagree with @RezaAghaei.  CellFormatting *might* work but only if the column is visible.  You could have a bool column which does not show which you use to trigger these paints.  In that case RowPrePaint might work better (I'd be marking/highlighting the *row* not just one cell)

Comment: @Plutonix I am still lost as to how i would initiate CellFormatting with the button I am using to search the datagridview...

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, `RowPrePaint` is probably more efficient because it raises for each row just once. But also `CellFormatting` will do the trick, regardless of having a specific cell visible or invisible, because we want to use that event for the row (any of cells in fact).

Comment: @Plutonix I can share an example if the question got opened.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I believe its open now...

Comment: *You* dont initiate events.  You should scramble over to MSDN and read up on the events mentioned.  They make life much easier and your code will be faster than looping 100k rows.  And of course decide whether this is a search, filter, select or highlighting operation.

Comment: Hmmm... `RowPrepaint` just like you were told to do outside SO. ;)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Your answer below works great; however I am unable to add to the criteria. So, i perform one search with one criteria it works great, but if i search for another criteria it un-highlights the previous one instead of adding to it... is there a way to do this in the example you gave?

Comment: Here is the criteria: `If data.Field(Of String)("FirstName").ToLower()                                                  .StartsWith(filter.ToLower()) Then` You can use any criteria which you want. In the example I just used `FirstName`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have made that part variable already with a string, what I am saying is that I would like to search for one criteria and then search for another afterward. Having both collections of qualifying records remaining the color red. Right now it only keeps the last criteria searched for red.

Comment: You can use different solutions, for example: Each criteria is a `Func<DataRow, bool>`. You can add each criteria to a `List<Func<DataRow, bool>>` and then evaluate them all using `OR` between them.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I apologize but I am such a beginner at all this, could you explain further or give me a detailed example? Also, you mentioned using OR between them, could I choose between AND and OR?

Comment: When you want each criteria makes some rows red and add some other criteria and additional too keeping current red rows, makes some new rows red based on new criteria, it means you need `OR`.  You should try something and then if you faced with a problem ask a new question. The start point is creating a `List(Of Func(Of DataRow, Boolean))` and in `Button1_Click`, instead of setting the filter, add a `Func(Of DataRow, Boolean)`, then in paint, check all crietria for a row and if one of them was true, make the row red.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ok cool I will give it a try, thanks for you help!

Comment: Feel free if to notify me if you asked a new question and I'll share an answer/comment if I had any :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CellFormatting` or `RowPrepaint` evant to apply some formatting to rows. In this case it's enough to check the criteria for the row which the event if fired for it and apply the format to the row if required. (Thanks to Plutonix for [mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386621/how-do-i-keep-rows-highlighted-in-a-datagridview-using-rowfilter/40387828#comment68026445_40386621) `RowPrePaint` which seems to be faster than `cellFormatting` in this case.)

Since the event is raised just for visible rows, there would not be a performance issue even if you have too many rows. Anyway having a `DataGridView` with too many rows is not a good idea and in such cases you should use a mechanism like [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx) or paging.

**Example**

Regardless of number of records, here is an example which I colorize rows which their `FirstName` starts with the text you entered in `TextBox1` if you press `Button1`. If you enter empty string in `TextBox1` and press `Button1` all rows will be shown in black.

To make the example working you need to have a `DataGridView1`, `TextBox1` and `Button1` on form.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim filter As String = ""
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName")
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName")
        dt.Rows.Add("John", "Doe")
        dt.Rows.Add("John", "Smith")
        dt.Rows.Add("Sara", "Allen")
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        filter = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, _
        e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
        If (e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex) Then Return
        Dim row = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)) Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Else
            Dim data = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, _
                DataRowView).Row
            If data.Field(Of String)("FirstName").ToLower() _
                                                 .StartsWith(filter.ToLower()) Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note**

If you apply `RowFilter` to the data table which you set as `DataSource` of `DataGridView`, it shows just filtered rows. So I didn't used it because you want to colorize filtered rows in red and others in black, so we need to show all rows.